# getting conflict while pulling files from branch, which files never touch by me

Tags: git, github

I'm following standard process to push the changes. So I committed few changes and now before going to push those changes I'm pulling files from that specific branch to make sure everything is up to date. But while pulling, few files getting conflicts which I never touch or modified.

Please guide, if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a whitespace issue, I would abort the merge `git merge --abort` run `git diff --check` to see if there's any trailing whitespace in the code you're trying to push. Then I would pull the changes into a new branch to see any whitespace errors with the same command.

Comment: Conflicts can be seen easily. My question was if i'm not modifying that specific file which has conflict why i need to resolve the conflict for that file?

Comment: Could you please clarify ! What does `git status` say (at this exact point) ?